# Espresso Testing Setting a variable

Tags: android-studio, testing, automated-tests, android-espresso

is it possible to set a variable from an activity that an Espresso Test is running on? Because when I try to set a variable like:

```
activityRule.getActivity().mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

I get the error:

```
lStateException: Must be called from main thread of fragment host
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
@get:Rule
val intentsTestRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java, false, true)

@Before
fun start {
   val intent = Intent().apply {
      putExtra("value", 1)
   }

   intentsTestRule.launchActivity(intent)
}
```

and then in MainActivity:

```
if (intent.getIntExtra("value", 0)) {
    //Do you stuff
}
```